# iphone - Battery using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges and desiredAccuracy

Tags: iphone, localization, power-management

I'm developing a localization app that runs in the background.

I'm using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to get the location updates of the user.

I know this method only uses the cell towers to determine the user location, but it saves battery, even if it's not very accurate.

I was wondering, what would be the effect combining this method with `desiredAccuracy` or `distanceFilter`?

Will it still be inaccurate and battery-friendly?

Or it will actually use the GPS and drain the battery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to use two CCLocationManager's and delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

First one for `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and the second one for `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`. Here is what I mean: your main `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and from time to time your choice how to do it call second `locationManager` and `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` immediatly when you get the first GPS location coordinates you call  `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]`. This approach is energy saver and you receive some `desiredAccuracy` GPS coordinates. Just make some personal logic to handle from witch `locationManager` comes and when to start and stop GPS.

Hope you understand my logic if not I will write some code. Now I'm not on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) states:

> It does not rely on the value in the distanceFilter property to generate events.

And as far as I can tell, there is now way to tell the location manager to use the `desiredAccuracy` for `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, thus braking the energy efficient nature of this method being available for application that "run" in background.